# Adding vps filesystem to home computer

Tags: debian, windows, vps

Is it possible to make a directory on my computer (W10) which is basically the vps machine, and I can just drag and drop it to put it into the vps?

Comment: what is "the vps machine"? Is this a question about WSL? I believe WSL2 allows you to access the WSL "drive" using `\\wsl.localhost\xxx` (where `xxx` is the name of the WSL instance)

Comment: Sorry I didnt explain it better, I was talking about a linux machine for example a pi, which is in my home network and I can ssh into it. I found it annoying connecting to it every time i wanted to push files into it

Comment: Couple of options. Install samba on the pi and export the pi's file system as a mountable CIFS share. Easier option is to install [sshfs](https://github.com/winfsp/sshfs-win) on the Win10 system and mount the pi home directory on the desktop. I'm still curious as to what "vps" stands for.